# What is mean of $\dot{\gamma}^j(t)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

In picture below ,I know $\dot{\gamma}(t)=\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}$, but , what is mean of $\dot{\gamma}^j(t)$? $\gamma(t)$ is a path on Riemannian manifold.

> [image]

Comment: It depends on the conventions of the source you are using, but I imagine that $\gamma$ is a curve in $\mathbb{R}^n$, in particular a function $\gamma : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ for some interval $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.  Then $\gamma^j$ likely refers to the $j$-th coordinate function of $\gamma$, i.e. $\gamma(t) = (\gamma^1(t), \gamma^2(t), \dots, \gamma^n(t))$.  And then the derivative of $\gamma$ is given by $\dot{\gamma}(t) = (\dot{\gamma}^1(t), \dots, \dot{\gamma}^n(t))$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That formula is written in local coordinates, so if the coordinates are $(x^1, \ldots, x^n):M\rightarrow U \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ then
$$ \gamma^j(t) := x^j(\gamma(t))$$
and
$$ \dot \gamma^j(t) := \frac{d}{dt}\gamma^j(t)$$

Answer (score 1):

I read $\dot{\gamma}^j$ as the $j$-th contravariant component of the time derivative of $\gamma$.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean $\dot{\gamma}^j(t)$ ?
Here $\gamma^j$ means the $j^\textrm{th}$ component of $\gamma$ you take the derivative of that and it is a function of time.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you will have a chart $\psi:U\to\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\gamma(t)\in U$. Then $\dot\gamma^j(t)=(\partial/\partial t)\psi^j(\gamma(t))$.